# React-native error : is also present at [:@react-native-firebase_admob] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-29

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, admob, firebase-admob

after installing react-native-firebase_admob i changed the manifest file with the value :

```
 <application>
   ******
   <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-4247389872422093~1957443376"/>
```

and then I get this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : 
           Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID@value
           value=(ca-app-pub-4247389872422023~1957443376)
           from AndroidManifest.xml:30:78-132

is also present at
           [:@react-native-firebase_admob] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-29
           value=().

Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-134
to override.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just follow the suggestion.

```xml
<application>
   ******
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-4247389872422093~1957443376"
            tools:replace="android:value"/>
```

Comment: i got this : `The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element type "meta-data" is not bound`

Comment: I added `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` attribute to manifest tag in the top and it worked !!

Answer (score 3):

here is the fix :

```
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
       ...
       <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                   android:value="ca-app-pub-4247389872422093~1957443376"
                   tools:replace="android:value"/>
```